# Is it possible to specify preferred node-placement for Docker Swarm services?

Tags: docker-swarm

If I have a Docker Swarm cluster consisting of 5 nodes, I'm aware that I can assign labels to particular nodes to guide which VMs services get deployed to. I.e. in the Docker Stack configuration:

```yaml
...
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.labels.service == postgres
```

Is it possible to specify a preferred placement node? Something like this:

```yaml
...
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.labels.service == postgres # This is always the first choice
      - node.labels.service == postgres_2 # This is the second choice
```

i.e. the logic I'm looking for is something along the lines of:

> Unless something is wrong with the node labeled `postgres`, deploy there. If something is wrong with that node (for example; a corrupted file system), then deploy to the node labeled `postgres_2`. When a node labeled `postgres` exists again as part of the swarm, redeploy to that node and delete the postgres service on `postgres_2`

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#placement-preferences